# What does a colored tile in the action tray mean?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I just updated to Windows 10. In my action tray there is a colored tile as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

What does this mean? If I left-click on the tile I'm taken to Settings, if I right-click on the tile I can only choose "Go To Settings", so the tile itself seems to function identically to the "All settings" tile also shown in the screenshot. A quick search in windows of "bluetooth" returns nothing which makes sense because I don't have bluetooth on this computer.

The colored tile makes me think that it means it's activated, however that makes no sense since I don't have blutooth. So what does a colored tile in the action tray actually represent?

Comment: Strange. If you don't have a bluetooth receiver this tile should not appear at all (colored or not). But yeah colored tile means it's activated/enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colored tile means, as user Tom Yan says, that the item is activated.

IF you are  completely  sure that you do not have bluetooth, it is strange that the PC turned it on.

In this case I would report the error to Microsoft. I would also install the latest wifi card drivers.